# Error:NullPointerException in android for dialog button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
edit_PASSWORD.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.change_password);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");
            EditText txtPassword = (EditText)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.changepwd);
            EditText txtVpassword = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.changevpwd);
            Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnch_ok);
            Button btnCancle = (Button)           findViewById(R.id.btnch_cancle);
            btnCancle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to create custom alert Dialog but when i click on btnCancle then program crash and get error:

> Error:NullPointerException in android for button click

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Post your error stack trace.

Comment: if `btnch_ok` and `btnch_cancle` buttons is inside `change_password` layout then use `dialog.findViewById` to initialize buttons

Comment: Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnch_ok);
            Button btnCancle = (Button)           dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnch_cancle);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this

```
   Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnch_ok);
```

and put

```
   Button btnOk = (Button) dialog. findViewById(R.id.btnch_ok);
```

same for btnCancle